# Import of matplotlib2tikz results in SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, matplotlib, tikz

I have a small python script (python 2.7) in which I want to use matplotlib2tikz, to generate tex files for my graphs.

I try to import the module as:

```py
import matplotlib2tikz
```

When I run the script, I immediately get the following error (it fails at the import):

````
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./get_violinplot.py", line 3, in <module>
import matplotlib2tikz
File "/x/.local/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/matplotlib2tikz/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
from matplotlib2tikz.save import get_tikz_code, save
File "/x/.local/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/matplotlib2tikz/save.py", line 238
def save(filepath, *args, encoding=None, **kwargs):
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```
````

After some quick searching, I got the impression that it might have to do with how the locales are set in the system (fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04). After generating them manually, the output of the $locale command in terminal shows the following:

````
```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```
````

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with locales. That module requires Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments of the save function declared in the way that Python2 doesn't support.

It works on Python 3.

```
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def function(filepath, *args, encoding=None, **kwargs):
...   pass
...
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, since I am using Python2. However I went to source code and simply exchanged ther order of "*args" and "encoding=None" in the definition of the function save (line 256 in save.py). For my purpose this solved the problem.

Comment: Aha, I will give it a try as well. Thanks for the tip!